# Laravel displaying file contents stops the scrips

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making an admin panel and inside the panel you should be able to edit php templates directly inside a textarea (using codemirror library) and then save them.

My issue occurs only when I load a template which contains the blade syntax for example: {{ auth()->user->check() }}. Otherwise, loading a template with HTML only works. The source page displays the code normally and filtered as well but the page just turns blank when using blade syntax.
[image: 1]

My code: (For testing purposes I explicitly told it to load a file)

```
public function getTemplates() {
    $templates_dir = resource_path('views\templates');
    $templates = File::allFiles($templates_dir);
    $files = [];
    foreach ($templates as $template) {
        $files[] = [
            'path' => $template->getPathName(),
            'file' => $template->getFileName()
        ];
    }
    $content = File::get($files[2]['path']);

    return view('admin::templates')
        ->with('files', $files)
        ->with('content', $content);
}
```

Comment: You get a blank page but no error? Not even in the logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs, I do see the page being rendered but then it turns blank as soon as it reaches the textarea (removes everything from the body). I've also tried using file_get_contents, but it yields the same results. There must be some kind of way because I've seen a CMS based on laravel do this.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: The latest. 5.4

Comment: But... what are you doing? Rewriting the \*.blade.php files in the *resources* files?

Comment: No...I'm getting the contents of the blade files in order to display it in a textarea. I want to be able to edit the contents of the file and then use File::put method to save it.